# I can't reproduce mockup gradient

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to do the html css integration of a web mockup.

In this css mockup I have this css code :

```
.Rectangle {
 border-radius: 16px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 4px;
 border-image-source: linear-gradient(228deg, #ffffff 64%, #ffd43c 3%, #ffd43c 3%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

When I copy this in my code and I test it on browser, it is not working, I have that as a result :

There is no degraded effect and no border radius in the result. Any solutions please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border-image` and `border-image-slice` are not compatible with `border-radius`. If you need to add a border radius you'll have to use a pseudo-element like `::before` that is positioned behind the `div`.

```css
.rectangle {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  color: #000;
  background-clip: padding-box; 
  border: solid 4px transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.rectangle::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: -4px;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background: linear-gradient(40deg, #ffd43c 50px, transparent 140px);
  }
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">Label</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but with this solution it affect responsivity, I use bootstrap system grid, try to put your code in a col and in row , after resizing, border become very small and it width is not fixed

Comment: See updated answer. The gradient border should remain the same size no matter how wide the `div` is.

Comment: I still have the same problem , try to expand you snippet on other window and resize it to small devices and you will see that the label is out  of frame and the border is deformed and becomes a square in the end :(

Comment: Are you looking at my updated answer? As you can see the color stops in the linear gradient remains constant at `50px`/`140px`. Which keeps the gradient border the same size no matter the viewport: https://ibb.co/yfFGm7H